# Owl carousel autoplay speed issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, owl-carousel

I am using owl carousel to animate some products on a website. This worked for a while but all of a sudden it's glitched. I get the idea that the speed is incredibly high, so I've tried setting a custom speed, but no matter what option I try, the result stays the same.

To see exactly what I mean you can look at the website: [here](http://karsteninstallatie.nl/)

Why is it behaving like this?

The option now is: `autoplay: true`
With `autoPlay: true` (notice the capital P) the carousel stops completely playing and with `autoplay: 3000,`the issue is still there.

Comment: you just want to make speed low of the slider ?

Comment: Just make it behave like a normal autoplay slider. Every 3 or 4 seconds, now it goes fullspeed and looks like its glitched.

Comment: Add your carousel code here or in jsfiddle.

Comment: please paste your jquery code into the question which one currently using into HTML file also did your try autoplayTimeout:5000, ?